# Como usar o widget Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu já vi a própria documentação do android já fiz todos os passos de outros fóruns e ainda não consegui usar toolbar no meu layout de tela.

> **Como devo prosseguir passo a passo em relação a implementação e utilização no meu
>   layout o toobar?**

Comment: Infelizmente não consigo dizer exatamente o erro, porque ainda não disponibilizaram o código fonte da última versão do `appcompat`. Chuto que é o tema ou está usando `setSupportActionBar` antes do `setContentView`. Poderia verificar esses pontos?

Comment: na questão do tema eu tive q adicionar no manifest.xml a linha android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" pois antes estava só android:theme="@style/Theme"

Comment: e estou seguindo a risca do seu código, portanto setSupportActionBar está depois do setContentView.

Comment: Ok, troque o tema para `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`. Com esse tema, o seu app não terá `Action Bar`, e o `Toolbar` fará o papel de `Action Bar` no lugar.

Comment: funcionou^^ obrigado mesmo era somente isso então. Você conhece muito bem o android espero um dia chegar ao mesmo entendimento.

Comment: Acho que não deixei muito claro isso, vou melhorar isso na resposta. Adoro a plataforma Android, estou sempre tentando acompanhar as novas tecnologias. Uma dica que eu dou é tentar entender o que está por trás, vendo o código fonte sempre que tiver um erro estranho ou pra entender como funciona.

Comment: @Wakim muito obrigado mesmo pela suas dicas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Para usar o [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html), você tem duas opções:

1. Se seu aplicativo precisa suportar versões anteriores a **21** então deve usar o `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` em seus layouts;
2. Caso contrário basta usar o `android.widget.Toolbar`.

Para começar, infelizmente, o `Toolbar` precisa estar em todos os layouts. Por questões de configurações de atributos de tema e posicionamento. Se instanciar o `Toolbar` e adicioná-lo manualmente no layout pode ser complicado ter de configurar sua posição e adicionar todos os atributos para estilizá-lo.

Lembrando que nessa resposta, é preciso importar a **library** do `appcompat v7 21`, ou adicionando o jar se for no Eclipse, ou importando a dependência se for no Android Studio. E como o `appcompat` depende da `support library v4`, ela precisa ser adicionado também.

Como estou usando o Android Studio, utilizo essas duas dependências:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
```

**Atenção**, se está usando o **Toolbar** como substituto da **Action Bar**, é preciso usar um tema sem o `ActionBar`. Para isso use os temas com final `NoActionBar`, tanto do `appcompat` quanto na versão 21. Um dos temas que uso eu uso do `appcompat` para esse propósito é o `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Um exemplo de layout usando o `Toolbar` é:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar_support" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/am_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Nesse caso, utilizei o `include` por questões de reaproveitamento (**DRY**), supondo que o `Toolbar` terá sempre os mesmo atributos em todos os layouts não faz sentido repetir em todos os lugares.

A posição dele pode variar a vontade no layout, e isso é uma das vantagens de se utilizar o `Toolbar`.

Definição do `Toolbar` no `include`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ab_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/ab_height"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Se estiver usando `android.widget.Toolbar`, a definição ficaria:

```
<android.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ab_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/ab_height"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light" />
```

---

Na `Activity`, algumas coisas precisam ser feitas.

Se quiser usar o `Toolbar` como um substituto para o `ActionBar`, basta usar o método `setSupportActionBar` (appcompat) ou `setActionBar` (Android 21) após o `setContentView`. Se está usando o `appcompat`, é primordial que sua `Activity` seja uma subclasse de `ActionBarActivity`.

Exemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Dando a responsabilidade de Action Bar para o Toolbar
    Toolbar tlb = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(tlb);
    // ou
    //setActionBar(tlb);

    // Apos isso, podera configurar sua Action Bar normalmente
    // Por exemplo:
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

**Para usar `setSupportActionBar` ou `setActionBar`, é preciso usar um tema que não tenha `Action Bar`, senão terá problemas. Pois está adicionando um `Action Bar` a uma `Window` que já tem um. Para isso use um dos temas com sufixo `*.NoActionBar` (e.g: `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, `Theme.Material.NoActionBar` e etc...)**

Em relação a construção de menus, usando `setSupportActionBar` ou `setActionBar`, as demais *callbacks* (`onCreateOptionsMenu`, `onOptionsItemSelected` e etc...) continuam sendo chamados igualmente. Logo não é preciso realizar nenhuma alteração no código.

Caso não esteja setando o `Toolbar` como `ActionBar`, é preciso usar o método `Toolbar.inflateMenu` para adicionar itens de menu ao `Toolbar`.

---

## Algumas observações importantes

1. Se usar um dos temas sem **Action Bar** (e.g: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`), e não setar o `Toolbar` usando o `setSupportActionBar` ou `setActionBar`, irá ter problemas com `NullPointerException` nas chamadas do `getSupportActionBar` ou `getActionBar`.
2. Se estiver usando **Action Mode** com o `Toolbar` no topo da tela, o `Toolbar` não é sobreposto pela barra do **Action Mode** , como no `Action Bar` padrão. A barra do **Action Mode** fica acima do `Toolbar`. Para evitar esse problema recomendo que esconda o `Toolbar` durante o **Action Mode**.

   Um exemplo seria:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();

       inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_deck_cab, menu);

       Toolbar tlb = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);        
       tlb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
       Toolbar tlb = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);        
       tlb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
   ```
3. Nessa nova versão, houve a depreciação dos métodos relacionados aos modos de navegação do `Action Bar` (e.g: `setNavigationMode`, `setSelectedNavigationItem` e `setListNavigationCallbacks`), logo se usa navegação por abas ou lista (`NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` ou `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`), deverá migrar para o `Toolbar`.

   Essa migração pode ser feita adicionando `View's` ao `Toolbar`, já que ele é um `ViewGroup`. Para navegação por abas, poderá adicionar um [`PagerTabStrip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html), ou semelhantes, no `Toolbar`. Se estiver usando navegação por lista, poderá adicionar um [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) ao `Toolbar`, e conseguirá o mesmo efeito.

## Referências:

1. http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html
2. https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: já esta quase dando certo^^ obrigado mesmo.. somente da um erro na activity dizendo que precisa do seguinte código: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); e eu adicionei antes do setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); depois da o seguinte erro : requestFeature() must be called before adding content, procurei muito nos foruns e não achei solução.

Comment: Hmm, estranho esse erro, esse foram todos os passos que fiz pra migrar do `Action Bar` para o `Toolbar` e não deu erro nenhum. Onde esse erro ocorre? poderia colocar a mensagem inteira e o local? Eu não recomendo chamar o `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)` porque ele vai adicionar o `ActionBar` e não é necessário.

Comment: ok eu so chamei o requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) tinha dado um erro anterior, tive q adicionar... mas vou tirar e mostrar o erro no meu post.

Comment: Sobre usar o Action Mode, o Toolbar também pode ser sobreposto usando `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` no tema do app ao invés de ser feito programaticamente. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443403/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7

Comment: @Luídne, hmmm, não sabia disso. Bem legal saber desse atributo.

Comment: Eles complicam as coisas as vezes se antes era sobreposto porque agora não. Ai que raiva passei horas achando que estava fazendo alguma coisa errada pois no https://developer.android.com/ não informa isso.