# Slide Menu usando Sherlock sem ActionBarDrawerToggle que está obsoleto

Tags: android, actionbar

Tenho visto muitos exemplos para implementar o slide menu usando a famosa SherlockActionBar, mas todas usam o ActionBarDrawerToggle que esta obsoleto. Alguém tem um exemplo de implementação de um slide menu usando Sherlock sem ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: Recomendo usar o ActionBar do `appcompat` ao invés do ABS. O ABS do Jake Wharton esta de certa forma depreciado devido a falta de atualização. Além disso, o `aappcompat` fornece mais recursos. Obs: recomendo dar uma olhada no Toolbar. A tendência é que com o Material Design, ele seja o padrão de uso no ActionBar. Sobre o Toolbar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38883/como-usar-o-widget-toolbar.

Comment: Entendi, mas estou usando slide tabs e não vi nenhum exemplo atual com a appcompat. Você teria algum?

Comment: Seria isso: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html?

Comment: Não amigo, porque nesse caso as tabs não ficam na actionBar me causando um problema de design.