# É possível utilizar ActionBar no Android de maneira nativa?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo algumas aplicações de teste e acabei me deparando com algo que tem me causado muitas duvidas, as bibliotecas de suporte do Android. Tentei desenvolver um aplicativo que utiliza *ActionBar* de maneira nativa (sem suporte), funciona perfeitamente no emulador, porém quando tento no meu smartphone, o item do menu que está com `android:showAsAction="never"` não é exibido, seguem as configurações e o código que tenho.

> **Nota:** no emulador o item com `android:showAsAction="never"` aparece dentro dos três pontinhos.

Emulador: Android Lollipop (API 21) 
Smartphone: Android KitKat (API 19)

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Você clicou em procurar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Você clicou em editar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_1"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Procurar" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_2"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Editar" />
</menu>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.exemplo.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.exemplo.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />

</resources>
```

Seguindo [esse link do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored) eu consegui fazer com a biblioteca de suporte, porém notei que o tamanho do `.apk` de 53,6 KB (sem suporte) foi para 0,9 MB (com suporte) e o espaço utilizado no smartphone foi de 72 KB (sem suporte) para mais de 3 MB (com suporte). Então minhas duvidas são as seguintes:

- É possível fazer um aplicativo usar *ActionBar* sem a biblioteca de suporte (para dispositivos com API 15 ou superior)?
- Quando eu realmente devo usar as bibliotecas de suporte?

**Extra**

> The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

Segundo esse trecho acima, teoricamente a *ActionBar* deveria ser nativa a partir da API 11 ou estou confundindo assuntos diferentes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ActionBar pode ser usado de forma nativa, lembrando que o ActionBar é a barra inteira e não apenas o menu.

Acredito que o problema encontrado seja pela presença de um menu físico no seu dispositivo, é apenas um chute. No caso da `ActionBar` da biblioteca de suporte, ele usa o `ActionBar` nativo. Mas a diferença é quem implementa a organização dos menus, que no caso do Support Library é ele mesmo, pode haver alguma diferença no resultado final.

No caso do menu nativo, quando possui menu físico o **overflow menu** (três pontinhos) fica escondido, tendo que apertar o menu físico para as opções aparecem (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html). Isso ocorre para não causar ambiguidade (dois modos de fazer a mesma coisa).

Você pode usar esse hack para forçar a aparição, mas não é recomendado pois é bom manter a coerência em relação aos demais aplicativos.

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");

    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Fontes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button

Atualmente o ActionBar está entrando em desuso, a favor do `Toolbar`. O `Toolbar` é uma generalização do `ActionBar` por permitir um posicionamento genérico, maior controle e um maior poder de estilização em vários aspectos, no caso especial ele faz o papel de `ActionBar`.

Além disso ele veio com grande força por causa do Material Design, que possui alguns tópicos sobre ele na *guideline*: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars e http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/principles.html#.

Ele surgiu na versão 21, mas a própria biblioteca de suporte o implementa para versões inferiores. Se quiser ver como usa-lo: [Como usar o widget Toolbar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38883/como-usar-o-widget-toolbar).

---

A biblioteca de suporte possui muito mais funcionalidades que apenas o `ActionBar/Toolbar`, é bom dar uma olhada nas funcionalidades: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html.

Lembrando que são vários módulos quase independentes:

- Support Library v4
- Support Library v7 (depende do Support Library v4):

  - Appcompat
  - Gridlayout
  - Media-router
  - Cardview
  - Palette
  - Recyclerview
- Support Library v8
- Support Library v13

De fato, como a biblioteca de suporte é muito extensa em funcionalidade, ela acaba pesando. Vale a pena avaliar se esse "custo" compensa em relação ao benefício que você terá. Lembrando que a grande maioria (não tenho dados estatísticos, é apenas uma conjectura) dos aplicativos possuem tamanhos muito maiores (porque usam muitas outras bibliotecas).

Um aplicativo legal para verificar isso é o [*Detective Droid*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.michaelcarrano.detectivedroid), que lista quais bibliotecas um determinado aplicativo possui.

Na minha opinião, está quase na hora de começar a ignorar certas versões. Segundo o [Dashboard do Android](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), existem apenas 7,4% dos aparelhos com o GingerBread. É um pequeno número mas não sei se poderia ser ignorado nesse exato momento, mas em breve.

Só essa estatística já levaria o abandono das Support Libraries, mas as vezes a implementação que ela faz de várias funcionalidades são bem mais estáveis que as nativas, que não sofrem correções, ao contrário da Support Library. Isso pode ser visto na lista de revisões: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html.

Acho que esse esse post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295497/fragment-or-support-fragment já cita um problema enfrentado com os `Fragment's` nativos.

Comment: Realmente é isso, não sabia desse detalhe do botão físico, o emulador provavelmente não tem essa configuração habilitada (se é que isso é possível).

Answer (score 0):

Além do que o @Wakim disse:

Se você não usar as bibliotecas de compatibilidade, você vai ver que seu aplicativo poderá ter um visual levemente diferente, dependendo da versão do Android e do fabricante do aparelho. Usando o tema Holo, você vai ter um aplicativo com cara de "velho", sem usar o Material Design. Dependendo do seu público-alvo, isso pode ter um grande impacto.

Além disso, pesquise sobre o proguard (https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html). Ele diminui o tamanho final do apk e do aplicativo após a instalação. Você pode ativar ele no comando "minifyEnabled" do seu build.gradle. Dá para encontrar no Google uma configuração que otimize para as bibliotecas de suporte, mas o AndroidStudio já fornece um básico.

Por padrão, o Gradle só executa o proguard quando você constrói o apk para publicação (buildTypes > release > minifyEnabled), porque ele demora para executar.